# How to build kernel with different flags?

Tags: kernel, compiling

Following the instructions here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) I built a development version of the kernel.

I copied the old config, called `make oldconfig` and then modified `.config` in the source tree in order to set a configuration flag:

```
CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG=y
```

Then I built it with `` make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom `` and installed the resulting packages with `dpkg -i`, yet the new flag has no effect:

```
$ uname -r
3.17.0-031700rc5-generic
$ grep CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG /boot/config-$(uname -r)
# CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG is not set
```

How can I compile a kernel with different flags in Ubuntu?

Comment: When you edited .config, did you read the text at the top? It says _Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT._ After using `make oldconfig`, try to use `make menuconfig` and use that to enable ACPI debug. It'll take care of the dependencies the various config options have.

Comment: I checked `menuconfig`. In the ACPI menu, the option `Debug statements`, whose additional information tells it is `CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG`, is checked.

Comment: Is it wrong to edit the kernel parameters as a text file?

Comment: It's not wrong per se, but some config options depend on others, the target `menuconfig` takes care of that.

Comment: In the end, it was a silly thing. I was choosing the wrong kernel in GRUB.